# Is there a way to dynamically query a postgres db from Flask user inputs?

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I need to dynamically query my Postgres database based on a Flask web app user input. I had it working in Python, but when I moved it to Flask it stopped working. I've narrowed it down to an issue with variable insertion into the query.

```
def predict_page(): 
    address_lookup = '10 West 28 Street' 
    # eventually this would take a user input like below 
    # address_lookup = request.args.get('address') 
    sq = """SELECT noise, population_density, median_home_value, 
            median_household_income, yearbuilt, vacant FROM     
            lookup_table WHERE address = %(input_address)s;""" 
    param = {'input_address':address_lookup} 
    query_results = pd.read_sql_query(sq, con, params = param)                   
    query_results = query_results.to_json() 
    return query_results
```

When I explicitly write the address in the query instead of a variable, it works.

```
def predict_page(): 
    sq = """SELECT noise, population_density, median_home_value,          
    median_household_income, yearbuilt, vacant FROM lookup_table 
    WHERE address = '10 West 28 Street';""" 
    query_results = pd.read_sql_query(sq, con) 
    query_results = query_results.to_json() 
    return query_results
```

Comment: I am voting to close this because the actual problem is only the missing single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you are missing are the single quotes in the `sq` string:

```
address_lookup = '10 West 28 Street'
sq = """SELECT noise, population_density, median_home_value, 
median_household_income, yearbuilt, vacant FROM
lookup_table WHERE address = '%s';""" % address_lookup

print sq
```

**Output:**

```
SELECT noise, population_density, median_home_value, 
median_household_income, yearbuilt, vacant FROM
lookup_table WHERE address = '10 West 28 Street';
```

**Note**

I wrote this answer so that it can be run stand-alone as I wanted to focus on the problem of the missing single quotes. Anyone using `read_sql_query` should probably use whatever parameter passing syntax is required to allow the server to do input sanitization. You **DO NOT** want to bypass server side parameter validation by using Python formatting to insert the parameters into the SQL query string.

Comment: Ah, yes I think the % insertion at the end of the string is much better. Is there a way I can modify this to accept two WHERE clauses? (e.g., WHERE address = '%s' AND zipcode = '%s' % address_lookup, zipcode_lookup)?

Comment: I think you still want to use the whatever query syntax you were using because there may be some server side parameter [sanitization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanitization) I am unaware of. I only wrote my answer this way because it isolates the problem from the rest of the code and allows the answer code to be run without imports.

Comment: I actually ended up getting it working like this: `sq = """SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table WHERE address = '{0}' AND zipcode = {1};""".format(address_lookup, zipcode_lookup)` and your answer helped me get there, thanks!